# What do $L$-functions of curves over $\mathbb Q$ tell us about the curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-zeta, l-functions

Following up this thread: [$L$-function of an elliptic curve and isomorphism class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823191/l-function-of-an-elliptic-curve-and-isomorphism-class)

I'd like to ask some more questions for the case of smooth projective curves $C$ over $\mathbb Q$

To be more precise, take this definition ( https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.hindry/Notes_rev_Brasilia.pdf, (2.2)):

$$L(\rho,s)=\prod_{\mathfrak p}\det(1-\rho(\mathrm{Frob}_p)p^{-s}\mid V^{I_{\mathfrak p}})^{-1}$$
where $\mathfrak p$ runs over the primes of $\mathbb Q$, or more generally: the number field $K$. And $V=H^1_{et}(C,\mathbb Q_\ell)$.

1. Is there a similar statement for curves of higher genus? I.e. if two $L$-functions $L(C,s)$ and $L(C',s)$ coincide, what can be said about $C$ and $C'$?
2. Are there further interesting properties that can be read off the $L$-function $L(C,s)$, and not the curve $C$ itself?
3. Assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis holds for $L$-functions of  curves over $\mathbb Q$, what does that imply about the curve?

Best,

Dan

Comment: First, what is your definition of the $L$-function of a curve $C$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Perhaps you want to fix, instead, a curve $C/\mathbb{Z}$ (this is essentially done away with for elliptic curves because you have Neron models, or natural singular models), and then you could define it as $\zeta(C,t)/\zeta(\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Z},t)$? There are Neron models for positive genus curves (IIRC), but maybe it's safe to just fix a model regardless. Or maybe you want to define it as $L(\rho,s)$ where $\rho=H^1(C,\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: It is essentially equivalent to know that $\text{Jac}(C)$ and $\text{Jac}(D)$ are isogenous. If $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves then $E=\text{Jac}(E)$ and $E'=\text{Jac}(E')$ which gives you the result you linked. Is that the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: That is an answer to my first point. Is there something stronger, i.e. my second and third question?

Comment: I don't know what 2. would mean. Since $L(C,s)$ depends on $C$ of course anything readable from $L(C,s)$ is readable from $C$. I also don't know what the GRH for curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ is. I searched through your reference and didn't find anything. If one gives a model for $C$ then one can relate the $L$-function to the $\zeta$ function and that probably satisfies (wahtever your definition is) the RH by the Weil conjectures.

Comment: Possibly you're interested in things like the Birch and Swinnterton-Dyer conjecture?

Comment: @Kimball: If there's a generalization of that to curves of genus 2 and higher, yes.

Comment: @Dan Again, it will just the BSD conjecture for the abelian variety $\text{Jac}(C)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis the Weil's RH is for local $\zeta$ functions, not for a [global one as here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Weil_zeta_function#Example:_elliptic_curve_over_Q) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_L-function) ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yeah, like I said--I'm not positive which possible interpretation of RH this might mean. It could just mean whether or not we know the Artin conjecture for $H^1(X,\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$, I suppose, but it's non-obvious to me. I defer, as expected, to the OP to specify.

Comment: @AlexYoucis for the OP 3rd question, if we assume all the conjectures, what does it mean for the curve, or its L-function (if it is easier when it is an elliptic curve) other than [what is mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture#Consequences) ?

Comment: @user1952009 I'm still not following--I apologize if I'm being dense. In what you linked it's essentially consequences of BSD assuming the *normal* Riemann hypothesis--not the fact that $L(E,s)$ has continuation to $\mathbb{C}$ with pole at $1$, etc (although that is also needed). But, assuming all the conjectures I don't know immediately nice things that can be said. Namely, I assume that part of 'assuming everything' is that $L(\text{Jac}(C),s)$ is automorphic which, likely, can be used to solve similar things to the congruent number problem (I don't know about Bhargava estimates for

Comment: higher-dimensional abelian varieties). Sorry I can't be of more help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Let $A:=\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers and let $S$ be a scheme of finite type over $A$. If $\pi:X \rightarrow S$ is a scheme of finite type over $S$, you may define the Hasse-Weil L-function $L(X,s):=\prod_{x \in X^{cl}} \frac{1}{1-N(x)^{-s}}$. Here $N(x)$ is the number of elements in in the residue field of $x$. Since $x$ by definition is a closed point it follows $N(x)$ is an integer. If $\pi':Y\rightarrow S$ is another scheme of finite type and $X_t\cong Y_t$ are isomorphic for any closed point $t \in S$, it follows $L(X,s)=L(Y,s)$. In particular if $E,F$ are vector or projective bundles of the same rank over $S$ it follows $L(E,s)=L(F,s)$. Hence if $E$ and $F$ have the same L-function this does not imply that $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic. Hence if $S=C$ is a "curve" it follows vector or projective bundles over $C$ are not determined by their Hasse-Weil L-functions.